# What considers to be a get request for Amazon s3 using boto3 library?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3

I am using AWS lambda and Amazon s3 for storage. Amazon s3 has some pricing for get requests of bucket. But what is get request considering using Python boto3. For example, i want to get 100 last uploaded objects but i have 1000 objects in a bucket. Here's what i do

```
for obj in list(buck.objects.all())[-100:]:
    key = obj.key
    body = obj.get()['Body'].read()
    #something
```

My question is does list(buck.objects.all()) mean i get all 1000 objects and pay for 1000 get requests or i really get only 100 objects as i want?

Comment: You're making 1x list request, and up to 100x get requests.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TL;DR, it will do a `ListObjects` and then 100 `GetObject`s.

> Resources represent an object-oriented interface to Amazon Web Services (AWS). They provide a higher-level abstraction than the raw, low-level calls made by service clients.

So the answer is no, resource will make requests on demand. In your example, since you wrote a for loop over 100 objects, it will do a `ListObjects` low-level action. Then since the `obj.key` information is already provided in `ListObjects` call, it will not make extra calls like `HeadObject`. Next, since you requested the object content for each of your 100 objects, Boto3 will do one `GetObject` for each of them.